# KendoWindow & AngularJS: setting window content doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHDwnbyeGtb4ddWGlIyZ?p=preview) you can see three kendo windows, the first two declared with AngularJS directives, and the third with jQuery. The content is set in the three windows, but it's only displayed in the jQuery window. What am I doing wrong? Why the first two windows are blank?

This is the HTML:

```
        <div kendo-window="win1" k-title="'Win 1'"
          k-width="300" k-height="200" 
          k-content="'<h1>Some Text 1111</h1>'"></div>

        <div kendo-window="win2" k-title="'Win 2'"
          k-width="200" k-height="200"
          k-content="htmlContent"></div>

        <div id="win3"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.htmlContent = '<h1>Some Text 2222</h1>';

}


$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#win3").kendoWindow({
          visible: true,
          width: "400px",
          height: "200px",
          title: "Win 3"
        });

  var kendoWindow = $("#win3").data("kendoWindow");
  kendoWindow.content("<H1>Some text 3333</H1>");
  kendoWindow.center().open();

});
```

**UPDATE**

I see in the console that kendo tries to load a file in k-content instead of taking the text:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://run.plnkr.co/0dvkHRto0wShGuIS/%3Ch1%3E**Some%20Text%201111**%3C/h1%3E?_=1415936598247

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://run.plnkr.co/0dvkHRto0wShGuIS/%3Ch1%3E**Some%20Text%202222**%3C/h1%3E?_=1415936598248

So the question is how to make KendoUI show the html text directly and not think that k-content points to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window isn't created at the time that the controller is loaded. Therefore, instead of

```
$scope.htmlContent = '<h1>Some Text 2222</h1>';
```

use this

```
$scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(ev, widget){

  if (widget === $scope.win2) {
    $scope.win2.content("<h1>Some Text 2222</h1>");
  }

});
```